# Multiple slideshow-container

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, slideshow

i have a problem. I am new to building webpages. I am trying to build two exact the same slideshow container on my webpage. The containers are showing of nice. The problem is that the buttons under my slide-show containers both work for the upper one. The lower slideshow container is not working. It stays on the first picture. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Thanks a lot guys!!

```
<div>
      <div class="neergard-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 9</div>
          <img src="/Bilder Weinberg/Wohzimmer111.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 9</div>
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/WohzimmerSofaecke111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 9</div>
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/SchlafzimmerEinzelbetten111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">4 / 9</div>
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/Schlafzimmeroben111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">5 / 9</div>
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/KleideraufbewahrungOben111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">6 / 9</div>
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/Kücheblickraus111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">7 / 9</div>
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/KücheSitzecke111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">8 / 9</div>
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/Esstischwintergarten111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">9 / 9</div>
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/StühleWintergarten111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
      </div>
      <br />

      <div style="text-align: center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(7)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(8)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(9)"></span>
      </div>

      <script>
        let slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);

        function plusSlides(n) {
          showSlides((slideIndex += n));
        }

        function currentSlide(n) {
          showSlides((slideIndex = n));
        }

        function showSlides(n) {
          let i;
          let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
          let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
          if (n > slides.length) {
            slideIndex = 1;
          }
          if (n < 1) {
            slideIndex = slides.length;
          }
          for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
          }
          for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
          slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
          dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
        }
      </script>
    </div>

    <h3 class="KutscherFW">Kutscherwohnung</h3>
    <p id="kutscher">
      Kutscherwohnung Einer weitere traumhafte Ferienwohung in Strande bei Kiel.
      Kaum enfernt vom Wasser die frische Luft genießen.
    </p>

    <div>
      <div class="kutscher-container">
        <div class="kutscherFolie fade">
          <img src="/Bilder Weinberg/Wohzimmer111.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
        </div>

        <div class="kutscherFolie fade">
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/WohzimmerSofaecke111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="kutscherFolie fade">
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/SchlafzimmerEinzelbetten111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="kutscherFolie fade">
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/Schlafzimmeroben111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="kutscherFolie fade">
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/KleideraufbewahrungOben111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="kutscherFolie fade">
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/Kücheblickraus111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="kutscherFolie fade">
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/KücheSitzecke111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="kutscherFolie fade">
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/Esstischwintergarten111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="kutscherFolie fade">
          <img
            src="/Bilder Weinberg/StühleWintergarten111.jpg"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusFolien(-1)">❮</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusFolien(1)">❯</a>
      </div>
      <br />

      <div style="text-align: center">
        <span class="button" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="button" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="button" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
        <span class="button" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
        <span class="button" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
        <span class="button" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span>
        <span class="button" onclick="currentSlide(7)"></span>
        <span class="button" onclick="currentSlide(8)"></span>
        <span class="button" onclick="currentSlide(9)"></span>
      </div>

      <script>
        let folieNumber = 1;
        showFolie(folieNumber);

        function plusFolie(n) {
          showFolie((folieNumber += n));
        }

        function currentFolie(n) {
          showFolie((folieNumber = n));
        }

        function showFolie(n) {
          let i;
          let folie = document.getElementsByClassName("kutscherFolie");
          let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
          if (n > folie.length) {
            folieNumber = 1;
          }
          if (n < 1) {
            folieNumber = folie.length;
          }
          for (i = 0; i < folie.length; i++) {
            folie[i].style.display = "none";
          }
          for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i].className = buttons[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
          folie[folieNumber - 1].style.display = "block";
          buttons[slideNumber - 1].className += " active";
        }
      </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, both the slides below and above are calling the same function.

"currentSlide"

I think the slide below should call another function. "currentFolie"
And there's a typo. There is no "plusFolien" function. Maybe it's a "showFolie" function.

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped a lot! I could sort the problem with your help!!!